# React - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

A similar question about the same tutorial was asked already here. Sadly this is a more advanced part of the tutorial and I don't seem to get this.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')
    at fetchProduct (ProductScreen.js:16:1)
    at ProductScreen.js:19:1
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23150:1)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:24926:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24891:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24878:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:24866:1)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:27039:1)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:26984:1)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:26076:1)
```

My ProductScreen.js:

```
function ProductScreen({ match }) {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchProduct() {
      const { data } =  await axios.get(`/api/products/${match.params.id}`)
      setProduct(data)
    }
    fetchProduct()
  },[])
```

My App.js:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <main className="py-5">
        <Container>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<HomeScreen />} exact />
            <Route path='/product/:id' element={<ProductScreen />} />
          </Routes>
        </Container>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: can you console match and check whats the value of match ?

Comment: Where does `match` come from? Where do you expect it to come from?

Comment: My best guess is you haven't imported react router which I imagine is where the match is declared. Could you show your imports please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to `match` prop. Not sure from where you're getting that. To answer this better, Maybe you can add a link like codesandbox or something where we can reproduce the issue.

If you're using `react-router-dom`(react-router 6) then you can do something like this.

```js
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function ProductScreen() {

    const [product, setProduct] = useState([])
    const { id } = useParams();

    useEffect(() =>{
        async function fetchProduct() {
            const { data } =  await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`)
            setProduct(data)
        }
        fetchProduct()

    },[])
    
    return (<div></div>);
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped! It makes sense in a way. I am following a tutorial and they did it another way. I guess if you are using react-router-dom 6 instead of 5, a lotttt changes. Thanks!!!